# nodemon won't work if I try tu run a file that is in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, nodemon

I'm starting out with node.js and I installed nodemon for a project. I put the index.js file that I want to run and the package.json file in a folder called src so I created a script in my package.json that goes: `"dev": "nodemon src"` but when I try to run it using `npm run dev`, it produces an error saying that it's related to npm not being able to find a file. If I put the files outside of the src folder and change the script to `"dev": "nodemon index.js"` it does work. I'm not sure why this is happening and how should I fix it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about nodemon src/index.js?

Comment: I've tried that too but still doesn't work.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: `it produces an error saying that it's related to npm not being able to find a file` please show the exact error message you get.

Comment: try `"dev": "cd src && nodemon index.js"`

Comment: This is the error:

```npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/Carlos_Duque/Desktop/node-first-website/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Carlos_Duque/Desktop/node-first-website/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Carlos_Duque/.npm/_logs/2021-07-01T16_08_38_880Z-debug.log```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nodemon yourfoldername/jsfilename.js
```

The folder name should be without spaces. Don't use `cd` command to get into that folder, simply write your folder name then '`/`' and JS file name.